# How to remove facebook comment mirroring

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I disabled facebook comment mirror on setting.

[image]

But on my website show: Your comment may also appear on Kim Nguyễn's Facebook Page.
[image: Your comment may also appear on Kim Nguyễn's Facebook Page.]

Answer (score 0):

**Comment Mirroring** allows people to participate in a single conversation, whether comments come from your webpage or from your Facebook Page. When you share a link to your website on your Facebook Page, comments from that webpage will also appear as comments on your Facebook Page post and vice-versa. This creates a richer conversation on both your Facebook Page and on your website because the comments will appear in both places.

You can turn on comment mirroring in the moderation tool by going to the **Settings** tab. In order to turn on comment mirroring, you need to be a Page admin for the Facebook Page on which you want to enable mirroring.

If you want people to be able to include photos in comments with comment mirroring enabled, you must also turn on **Allow visitors to the Page to publish posts for your page**. To make comments mirrored correctly, your Facebook page needs to be public to everyone.

Comment mirroring takes effect on new webpages created after the setting has been enabled. Once comment mirroring is turned on for a particular webpage, there is no way to disable mirroring (you can only turn off mirroring for new webpages going forward), so if the auto close feature is enabled and it is shared to your Facebook Page, new comments can still be made from the Facebook Page post, but not from your webpage.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYOAE.png)

**Will people know that we’re mirroring comments?** When a person begins to write a comment on your website, they'll see a message that lets them know that their comment will also appear on your Facebook Page. The same message appears when a person begins to write a comment on an article posted to your Facebook Page.

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vN9p.png)

**How does moderation work?** All comments, whether left on the Facebook Page post or on the original article on your website, will show up in the main Facebook comment moderation tool, so all comments displayed on the article page can be moderated. If you hide a comment in the moderation tool, it will automatically be hidden on the Facebook Page, too.

Comment: You should mention that this is basically ripped from the documentation verbatim - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments

Comment: Yes, I tried based on this document working fine for me

Comment: That’s not the point. You did not write any of this yourself, but just copy&pasted it - without even mentioning that.

Comment: You have any solution to disable this?